# How can i use a switch with a spinner?

Tags: android, string, case, switch-statement, spinner

so i started android programming like a month ago, and i've got a probleme today.

The thing i want to do is : From a Item in the Spinner, when i select it there is a Text View changing on the back.

```
    spin.setAdapter(adapter_city);
    spin.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.string.Paris : description.setText("blah blah");
    }

}
```

and i would like the description fit with the resource.

Paris is in a xml called "cities", it's a value xml.
Thank you.

Comment: Well firstly, why are you switching on the id of the View (v.getId()) as opposed to the actual id/position of the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`, it will give you back to actual `String` you put in to the spinner. Then you can compare this with `getString(R.string.Paris)` to see if they are the same, and act accordingly. You cannot switch on a `String` in Java, so you just have to write a some `if` statements.